# element.style when there is no inline style

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm pretty new to JQuery but I'm trying to use the JQuery accordion to information on the page.  It's not displaying as I expected so I used Chrome to inspect the div tag.  The element.style is set to a height of 0px on the active tab so I can't even see what's in that div.  When I expand other divs in my accordion and suddenly all divs in the accorion have a height of 0.39999961853027344px (even the first one).

I'm not applying any style to the accordion control or the divs in it so I'm not sure why Chrome is showing these phantom heights in the element.style.

```
            <div id="accordion">
            <h3>Alerts</h3>
                <div>
                        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="myRelatedGV1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" />
                </div>
            <h3>Information</h3>
                <div>
                    123
                </div>  
            <h3>Conditions</h3>
                <div>
                    456
                </div>
            <h3>Assignments</h3>
                <div>
                    789
                </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        </script>
```

As you can see, I'm not applying any css to the accordion div of the divs inside it.

Initial style on the open div in the accordion according to Chrome:
    element.style {
        height: 0px;
    }

All divs in the accordion after an expand event according to Chrome:

```
element.style {
    height: 0.39999961853027344px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 14.300000190734863px;
    padding-bottom: 14.300000190734863px;
}
```

The HTML, according to Chrome, ends up looking like this:

```
#accordion > div.SettingsWrapper.ui-accordion-content.ui-helper-reset.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-bottom.ui-accordion-content-active


<div class="SettingsWrapper ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" role="tabpanel" style="height: 0.39999961853027344px; overflow: hidden;     display: block; padding-top: 14.300000190734863px; padding-bottom: 14.300000190734863px;">
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_myRelatedGV1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        //...data...
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

I've one-by-one commented out each of the style classes referenced in the html in chrome but it has had no effect.  And none of those classes have a height of 0 or 0.39999961853027344.  I can't figure out where those values are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

See **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zpLxJ/)**

If you don't pass the `heightStyle: "content"` option in your accordion initialization, it will, by default, set all accordions height equals the first DIV's height.

Meaning: if you first DIV isn't set, all other DIVs will automatically be zero.

Check [this](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height) post on jQuery Accordion Widget.

Comment: I tried adding heightstyle to the accordion call, and gave the table a height of 400px.  That made the table 400px but did nothing to the div.  So now I have to use the tiny scrollbar on the right to scroll down about 200px to see the content of the table.  The element.style of the div is still 0.

Comment: You must have stuff on your table. Do you have a `<tr>` and `<td>` elements? I see it's a ASPX Gridview inside the first DIV. How is it populated?

Comment: I did what you just said and it appears to be working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zpLxJ/1/)

Comment: Yes, the Gridview has data.  I have to scroll to see it because the div it's in is so tiny.  I still wonder if there's a style buried somewhere deep in our mess of CSS files (other developers are adding new css classes & files to the proj all the time) that's causing this to happen.  All the pages use a master page that references all the CSS files.  If I remove the master page from the equation, my OP code works so I think the accordion is set up properly.  I can't find anywhere in proj that sets div height 0 and nothing on the div itself so I don't know where Chrome is finds element.style

Comment: Have you tried putting the accordion initialization as the last script to run? I bumped into the same kind of problem and I had to destroy and build the accordion from scratch after data has been fetched.
Don't know how much I can help you with, since it may be a problem coming from the masterpage

Comment: I found the accordion script in jquery-ui-1.8.20.js and commented it out.  This broke the page so I know this is the right one.  I copied the method into my own js file and referenced it just before my call to the accordion method.  It works again.  Now I need to figure out what I need to change in the accordion method to force the height to be the size of the content instead of 0 or 0.399999

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54556/discussion-between-jeremy-and-cr0ss).